# regular express to get all the div(include the information) from a div?

Tags: python, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4K5O.png)

Hey, I just start to learn python, want to code a web scraping. The website I got, I only care about the name and price, but all the information was written in a one div which contains other three sub divs in there. The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="Product">
    <div class="product-image-and-name-container"></div>
    <div class="prices"></div>
    <div class="buy-now-button"></div>
</div>
```

I tied to use this line to get all the information from "Product"

```
 root_pattern = '<div class="Product">([\s\S]*?)</div>'
```

But only give the first div-"product-image-and-name-container" information, and then stop. Not get anything from the other divs.

Here is my all codes:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

class Shopping_Spider():
    url = 'http://www....com/Shop-Online/587'
    root_pattern = '<div class="Product">([\s\S]*?)</div>'
    name_pattern = '<div class="product-name">([\s\S]*?)</div>'
    price_pattern = '<span class="Price">([\s\S]*?)</span>'

    def __fetch_content(self):
        # page = urllib.urlopen(Shopping_Spider.url)
        r = Request(Shopping_Spider.url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        html_s = urlopen(r).read()
        html_s = str(html_s, encoding='utf-8')
        return html_s

    def __analysis(self, html_s):
        root_html = re.findall(Shopping_Spider.root_pattern, html_s)

        anchors = []

        for html in root_html:
            name = re.findall(Shopping_Spider.name_pattern, html)
            price = re.findall(Shopping_Spider.price_pattern, html)
            anchor = {'name': name, 'price': price}
            anchors.append(anchor)

        return anchors

    def go(self):
        html_s = self.__fetch_content()
        self.__analysis(html_s)


shopping_spider = Shopping_Spider()
shopping_spider.go()
```

Thanks in advance, I think my regular express is wrong, but do not know how to rewrite, I know it may easier use BeautifulSoup to deal with it, but just want to know is that possible I just use the regular express to get what I want!  Big Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, it's certainly quite hard. You can sometimes get away with regexes to get something done quickly but in this case you really, really should use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the inner content of the outer divs with a regex like

```
root_pattern = r'(?:<div class="Product">)(.*)(?:</div>)'
```

Above you define three capturing groups but reject the ones starting specified with the ?: in the start

But you have to set the dotall flag to include the \n char in the dot (.), that is all chars, specification, so later in your code use

```
root_html = re.findall(Shopping_Spider.root_pattern, html_s, re.DOTALL)
```

Then you can adapt the remaining patterns with the same principles.

Edit (important):

Jimmy, unless an expert in regexes shows up with a solution, go with the BeautifulSoup.

Unless your target html pages were that simple (they never are) this will not work in practice (despite working with the sample).Alex comment goes right to the point. Also feel free to un-accept my answer and give him the credits because I tend to believe the better advice will always be to go with BS (despite you asking for a regex alternative). You may always upvote this if you think it was somehow useful anyway.

The problem is that div tags can be arbitrarly nested in a document. The regex I presented captures everything between the start product div until the last div in the document (which will not work in practice). This is because * is "greedy". You can avoid that with ? following the *, but that you'll not solve anything as then it will capture to the first closing div. Also I see no way of matching a closing div with its start, because closing divs are all equal, and because of both arbitrary nesting, or structure changes shuch as having more listed divs inside the product div.

Not without starting to write code to somehow parse the html, which is exactly what BS is for.

Comment: While this works with the sample OP has given, it fails if there's more HTML including a later `<div>...</div>`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, you made me think about this and I totally agree with you. I have somehow thought that findall would extract all the inner blocks, which was not only wrong, but also quit odd as a thought, to begin with :)